# Brackets too large, inconsistent horizontal spacing

Tags: equations, xetex

I am sure similar questions have been asked here. However, I am not seeking help in adjusting the size of some specific symbols. Rather, I wonder if there is something wrong with my choice of fonts/packages that leads to visually unpleasing formatting. In fact, I hate how it currently looks like.

While subjective, let me identify some problems in the formulas below.

[image]

- Too big space between the log and the vertical bars in (1).
- Too large space around parentheses in (1), especially before the sign-function.
- Inner brackets in (2,3) are too large, they are even larger than the outer square brackets in (2).
- Larger spacing between log and | in (2) vs. vanishing spacing between arccos and ( in (3). **Just ugly.**
- One in principle needs to declare the sign-function as a math operator. It will improve spacing in 4, and make it worth in (1).

Below is the code to reproduce the equations

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,onecolumn,openright,final,oneside]{memoir}
%===============================================
\settrims{0.cm}{0.cm}
\setbinding{0cm} % space for binding
\setlrmarginsandblock{*}{3cm}{1} % spine = edge. Edge=3cm
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{*}{1} % upper=lower. Upper=3cm
\checkandfixthelayout
%===============================================
\usepackage{amssymb,mleftright}
\usepackage[]{mathtools,units}
\usepackage{stix}
\DeclareMathOperator{\thf}{\theta}
\begin{document}
\begin{align} 
  q_1&=\frac{y^2}{4z}\log|2r_4|+\log\sqrt{\nicefrac12 |r_4|}-\frac{r_2}{2z}\thf(y-1)\log|r_2|\nonumber\\
  &\qquad+\left(\frac{r_2}{4z}\log|1+z|+\frac{y^2}{4z}\log|y^2|\right)\mathrm{sign}(y-1),\\
  q_2&=\left[\frac{|r_2|}{4z}\log\left|\frac{(2+z)\sqrt{r_2 r_2}+z\sqrt{r_1r_3}}{(2+z)\sqrt{r_2 r_2}-z\sqrt{r_1r_3}}\right|
    -\frac14\log\left|\frac{\sqrt{r_1r_3}+2+z}{\sqrt{r_1r_3}-(2+z)}\right|\right]\left(\thf(-r_1)-\thf(r_3)\right),\\
  p_1&=\left[\frac{r_2}{2z}\arctan\mleft(\frac{(2+z)r_2}{z\sqrt{-r_1r_3}}\mright)
    +\frac12\arccos\mleft(\frac{2+z}{y\sqrt{-2r_4}}\mright)\right]\thf(-r_1r_3),\\
  p_2&=\frac{\pi r_2}{4z}\mathrm{sign}(r_2)\thf(-r_1r_3)+\frac{\pi r_4}{z}\thf(y-2)\thf(-r_4)\thf(r_3)-\frac{\pi y^2}{2z}\thf(-r_1).
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

As I said, I know how to individually tweak each of the points. But I wonder, if there is some global solution. Maybe that is just a problem of stix fonts that I am using?

Comment: Now you now why `|` is not a good fence. It is a symbol, unlike () which has the open and close type `|` is treated as a symbol and thus get a bigger space after log. Proper symbols are `\lvert` and `\rvert` and then abs via marhtolls becomes easier. Note that mathtools will automatically add open- and closeness to the symbols used in DeclarePairedDelimiter

Comment: The large space between ) and the sign søcomes from your use of left /right. I don't really see it as a problem here, but there is a package that provide variants of left/right that gives them proper spacing. The problem with left/right in this case is that right) is actually not a close symbol, left(... Right) is an inner atom so sign treats it like a normal symbol and leaves a space

Comment: @daleif You address the horizontal spacing. But what about vertical sizes, see third point about Eq.(2)?

Comment: That can be down to bad font design or misalign from ams. Btw your example code would be a lot easier to read if the ``\\`` are on lines of their own.

Comment: And yes multiletter math operators like sign needs to be declared a math operator to get the correct spacing, spacing in (4) before sign is wrong.

Comment: Note that the size difference between autoscalled [ and autoscalled | might also be a deliberate design choice.

Comment: @daleif This may well be a deliberate design. But do you know a better font? I think the vertical size of | and the horizontal spacing around ) are wrong in stix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### *Question*: Too big space between the log and the vertical bars in (1).

That's what `\lvert` and `\rvert` are for: `\log\lvert x\rvert` will have no space between the operator and the bar.

#### *Question*: Too large space around parentheses in (1), especially before the sign-function.

Actually I can't see this too large space. The parentheses in the second line of (1) are too big; `\bigg` size is better.

#### *Question*: Inner brackets in (2,3) are too large, they are even larger than the outer square brackets in (2).

Use `\Bigg` size for the inner brackets.

#### *Question*: Larger spacing between log and | in (2) vs. vanishing spacing between arccos and ( in (3). Just ugly.

Same as before.

#### *Question*: One in principle needs to declare the sign-function as a math operator. It will improve spacing in 4, and make it worth in (1).

Definitely.

#### Other fixes

I used `\\[2ex]` to separate equation and `split` for the first.

I transformed some `\mleft` and `\mright` into `\bigg` or `\Bigg`. Added a phantom to pair square roots in (3).

And the first thing I did was to remove the `\uglyfrac` (certainly `\nicefrac` is a bad name for it).

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,onecolumn,openright,final,oneside]{memoir}
%===============================================
\settrims{0.cm}{0.cm}
\setbinding{0cm} % space for binding
\setlrmarginsandblock{*}{3cm}{1} % spine = edge. Edge=3cm
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{*}{1} % upper=lower. Upper=3cm
\checkandfixthelayout
%===============================================

\usepackage{amssymb,mleftright}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stix}

\DeclareMathOperator{\thf}{\theta}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \begin{split}
  q_1&=\frac{y^2}{4z}\log\lvert 2r_4\rvert
      +\log\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\lvert r_4\rvert}
      -\frac{r_2}{2z}\thf(y-1)\log\lvert r_2\rvert
      \\
     &\qquad\qquad+\biggl(\frac{r_2}{4z}\log\lvert 1+z\rvert
      +\frac{y^2}{4z}\log\lvert y^2\rvert\biggr)\sign(y-1),
  \end{split}
\\[2ex]
  q_2&=\mleft[
         \frac{|r_2|}{4z}\log\Biggl|
           \frac{(2+z)\sqrt{r_2 r_2}+z\sqrt{r_1r_3}}
                {(2+z)\sqrt{r_2 r_2}-z\sqrt{r_1r_3}}
         \Biggr|
        -\frac{1}{4}\log\Biggl|
           \frac{\sqrt{r_1r_3}+2+z}
                {\sqrt{r_1r_3}-(2+z)}
         \Biggr|
       \mright]
       \mleft(\thf(-r_1)-\thf(r_3)\mright),
\\[2ex]
  p_1&=\mleft[
         \frac{r_2}{2z}\arctan\biggl(\frac{(2+z)r_2}{z\sqrt{-r_1r_3\vphantom{2}}}\biggr)
        +\frac12\arccos\biggl(\frac{2+z}{y\sqrt{-2r_4}}\biggr)
       \mright]
       \thf(-r_1r_3),
\\[2ex]
  p_2&=\frac{\pi r_2}{4z}\sign(r_2)\thf(-r_1r_3)
      +\frac{\pi r_4}{z}\thf(y-2)\thf(-r_4)\thf(r_3)
      -\frac{\pi y^2}{2z}\thf(-r_1).
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am very happy with your edits. Tiny differences, but they are decisive and make the equation look pleasant. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
Apparently I was interrupted at writing my answer, since it has not be finished. Unfortunately I didn't observe this till now and now, unfortunately again, planed discussion in chat room newer happen (I wait on you), and than it seems I haven't finished it.

This I is done now wit adding complete MWE, which -- to my opinion -- answer on all your subquestion on satisfactory way.

Most of spaces in your equations is deliberately defined by LaTeX and `mathtools`, so your equations not look badly ...  about shrinking spaces is not much to do automatically. You can select different symbols for some math operators, for  example space between `log` and `|2r_4|` can be reduced with use of `\log\abs{2r_4}` where `\abs` is defined as

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
```

Where are preserved `\left[`, `\right]` their height is determined by

```
\delimitershortfall-1sp
```

which increase height of the outer brackets for `1sp` from inner ones. For vertical distance between equations is used `[1ex]`, which can be chnged according to your test (for example to  `[2ex]`).

That are more or less all what can be done automatically. For further improvements -- if you like to introduce in equations -- you need manually tweak your equations. For example for less space between their elements with use of `\!` before/after them.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,onecolumn,openright,final,oneside]{memoir}
%===============================================
\settrims{0.cm}{0.cm}
\setbinding{0cm} % space for binding
\setlrmarginsandblock{*}{3cm}{1} % spine = edge. Edge=3cm
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{*}{1} % upper=lower. Upper=3cm
\checkandfixthelayout
%===============================================
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stix}
\DeclareMathOperator{\thf}{\theta}% ?
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\delimitershortfall-1sp

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
q_1 & = \frac{y^2}{4z}\log\abs*{2r_4} 
        + \log\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\abs*{r_4}} - \frac{r_2}{2z}\theta(y-1)\log\abs*{r_2}       \notag  \\
    &   \qquad+\biggl(\frac{r_2}{4z}\log\abs{1+z} + \frac{y^2}{4z}\log\abs*{y^2}\biggr)\sign(y-1),  \\[1ex]
%
q_2 & = \left[\frac{\abs{r_2}}{4z}
        \log\abs*{\frac{(2+z)\sqrt{r_2 r_2}+z\sqrt{r_1r_3}}
                       {(2+z)\sqrt{r_2 r_2}-z\sqrt{r_1r_3}}}
        - \frac{1}{4}\log\abs*{\frac{\sqrt{r_1r_3}+2+z}{\sqrt{r_1r_3}-(2+z)}}\right]
        \bigl(\thf(-r_1)-\thf(r_3)\bigr),                                                           \\[1ex]
%  
p_1 & = \left[\frac{r_2}{2z}\arctan\Biggl(\frac{(2+z)r_2}{z\sqrt{-r_1r_3}}\Biggr)
        + \frac{1}{2}\arccos\Biggl(\frac{2+z}{y\sqrt{-2r_4}}\Biggr)\right]\thf(-r_1r_3),            \\[1ex]
%
p_2 & = \frac{\pi r_2}{4z}\sign(r_2)\thf(-r_1r_3)
        + \frac{\pi r_4}{z}\thf(y-2)\thf(-r_4)\thf(r_3) - \frac{\pi y^2}{2z}\thf(-r_1).
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: You address the horizontal spacing. However, is it really needed to increase the vertical size of || in such simple situations? Moreover, || are still too large in (2).

Comment: @yarchik, on the showed way try to rewrote rest of your equations.  BTW, your equations don+t contain `||`. For size of parenthesis and brackets use manual settings as I do in showed example (I don't use `\left` ... `\right` constructions but `\biggl` ... `\biggr` (do you observe this?)

Comment: \biggl ... \biggr do improve visual appearance. However, all these ** local adjustments** is exactly my problem. I think it is a wrong approach to individually  adjust each equation to improve the appearance. Do you have a more general solution?

Comment: no, for adjusting height of braces exist only two posibilities: use `\left...` and `...\right` what you not liked or `\bigl...` (\Bigl, \biggl, \Biggl)  and and their right parts what you not like to do. I can't further help you. BTW, defined `\abs` in stared version `\abs*` accommodate height of delimiters to their contains height.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Just a clarification question: since you claim nothing more can be done to improve visual appearance, it seems in your solution the space ") sign" is slightly larger than ") log"? Is it just an illusion,  according to the typographic standards, shouldn't they be equal?

Comment: @yarchik no, it is not illusion. since there is `\abs*{...}` its delimiters heights are adopted to height of content inside of curly braces. if you not liked this, then use just `\abs{...}`.

Comment: But I am talking about the horizontal space and you refer to the height. What is the connection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100109/discussion-between-yarchik-and-zarko).

Comment: not before late evening/midnight.